# Codeigniter 3 How to load library session from library path

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try to load library session from another file in library path, i use these code to load the library but its cannot work

```
class Gdrive_api
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->load->library('session');
    }
}
```

Message Show

> Undefined property ::$load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the way to call another library from library path, it using get instance

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ci = &get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->library("session");
}
```